# Difference in where to pass the arguments using Dask

Tags: python, matplotlib, dask

I've been trying to plot many figures using `matplotlib`+`dask` through the package [xmovie](https://github.com/jbusecke/xmovie). I've experimented with expressing memory limits and such is two ways and have gotten different results. For example if I use

```py
client = Client(n_workers=18, memory_limit='0.5GB', processes=False)
parallel_plotting.compute()
```

I keep getting warnings like `distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 90% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)` and even occasional errors.

However, if I pass the arguments to the compute function such as

```py
parallel_plotting.compute(n_workers=18, memory_limit='0.5GB', processes=False)
```

everything seems to work fine.

Could someone please explain why these two ways of passing keywords are different? I have not been able to find the answer in the docs.